# When exim4 sends HELO/EHLO, how do I configure which host name it sends?

Tags: linux, smtp, domain-name, exim

Mails from my system are being rejected when the receiving server does HELO checking.  I believe my system is sending the wrong domain name.  I'm running exim4.  Googling for anything about exim4 and domains yields a nightmarish list of irrelevant results.  Similarly, googling for HELO rejections yields a horde of outlook users who need to turn on SMTP authentication.  I cannot for the life of me figure out this simple question: which hostname is exim sending and how do I change it?

Unfortunately, I can't watch what exim is sending over the wire, so I have no way to debug this myself.  I'm hoping someone has had this problem and just knows :).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Assuming the error is complaining about the HELO/EHLO data, you want to use the helo_data option on the smtp transport. The default is $primary_hostname.

```
remote_smtp:
    driver = smtp
    helo_data = host.example.com
```

More information is available in [the manual](http://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch30.html#SECID146).

If this isn't the case, you probably want to include some example rejection messages. Just the three digit code and the string after that.

Comment: Thanks!  After 10 more minutes of reading about how to even *change* an exim4 setting on a debian-based system, I set primary_hostname to the FQDN in /etc/exim4/exim4.conf.template and restarted exim4.  That did the trick!  My hostname is different from the FQDN and I am not using minimal_dns, thus the original problem.  Plus, only by modifying your manual link was I able to even *find* the docs on primary_hostname (exim is so google-trashed!).  Thanks again!

Comment: You probably don't want to update that file. I would recommend running update-exim4.conf --keepcomments and then copy /var/lib/exim4/config.autogenerated to /etc/exim4/exim4.conf and then modify that file.

Answer (score 4):

The command

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure exim4-config
```

should prompt you for the primary hostname to use.

Comment: this is not true anymore

Answer (score 4):

### Which hostname is exim sending ?

One can find the HELO name in exim4's logs.  Stop the exim4 daemon, then restart it manually with debugging enabled :

```
/usr/sbin/exim4 -bd -d+all 2>&1 | egrep 'HELO|EHLO'
```

(the `2>&1|egrep 'HELO|EHLO'` part is optional, it just redirects stderr to stdout, then pipe the log to `egrep`, which will filter everything but lines containing HELO or EHLO).

Send an email and there should be one or two lines in the following form :

```
SMTP>> EHLO foobar.example.com
```

The HELO name is `foobar.example.com`.

There are also several useful online checking tools which provide this information (and many useful others), e.g. :

- https://www.mail-tester.com (beware, only 3 free email checks per day) ;
- check-auth@verifier.port25.com (free) ;
- mailtest@unlocktheinbox.com (most of its feedback is not free, but for this purpose it is).

### How do I change it ?

Instead of editing the transport file as suggested by David, I'd rather use exim4 constant definitions (?) and set the name in `/etc/exim4/conf.d/main/00_local_settings` (in split configuration), e.g. :

```
REMOTE_SMTP_HELO_DATA=$sender_address_domain
```

Don't forget to run `update-exim4.conf` before to restart exim4.

### I set primary_hostname […] in /etc/exim4/exim4.conf.template

As mentioned by David, this is probably not the best idea.  In split configuration, you can set the primary hostname by adding

```
MAIN_HARDCODE_PRIMARY_HOSTNAME = subdomain.example.com
```

in `/etc/exim4/conf.d/main/00_local_settings`.  [It seems](https://serverfault.com/a/46591/143834) it would be `PRIMARY_HOST_NAME` in monolithic exim4 configuration.

Answer (score 3):

On Debian (Lenny) I found that you set hostname in `/etc/hostname` but that this is not recognised until reboot.

```
$ hostname newhostname
```

sets it right away (but is lost on reboot, so you have to do the two).

exim4 seems to report the same as `uname -n`, and I found that a useful way to test.

Answer (score 0):

The setting you want is called [primary_hostname](http://lists.alioth.debian.org/pipermail/pkg-exim4-users/2006-December/000849.html).

For debugging you can use

```
tcpdump -A port 25
```

to watch SMTP traffic in ASCII.