# Mails sent from another mailserver within the network are rejected (helo has been denied)

Tags: email, exim, mx-record

I am no real network administrator, so please bear with me.

In a small company we run a router that acts as a firewall and mail recipient. It forwards the mails to a Lotus Domino server in the NAT. We use the Lotus server for normal mail communication.

Now, for sending out newsletters, and since Lotus doesn't do that very well, we set up a small Ubuntu server running exim4. phplist is used to send the mails from this machine.

However, when sending mails, some providers seem to block us:

> This message was created automatically by mail delivery software.
>       A message that you sent could not be delivered to one or more of its
>       recipients. This is a permanent error. The following address(es) failed:
>       xxxxxxx@gmx.at
>       SMTP error from remote mail server after RCPT TO::
>       host mx0.gmx.net [213.165.64.100]: 550-5.7.1 {mx072} Sorry, your helo has been denied.
>       550 5.7.1 ( http://portal.gmx.net/serverrules )

Here's the exim4 configuration:

```
dc_eximconfig_configtype='internet'
dc_other_hostnames='mail.ourdomain.co.at'
dc_local_interfaces='127.0.0.1'
dc_readhost=''
dc_relay_domains=''
dc_minimaldns='false'
dc_relay_nets=''
dc_smarthost='192.168.1.1'
CFILEMODE='644'
dc_use_split_config='false'
dc_hide_mailname='false'
dc_mailname_in_oh='true'
dc_localdelivery='mail_spool'
```

Other mails seem to get delivered just fine. How would you go about solving this issue? Feel free to ask questions if details are missing. Thanks.

Update:

My `/etc/mailname` is: `mail.ourdomain.co.at`

When I reconfigure exim4:

```
root@mail01:~# sudo update-exim4.conf
sudo: unable to resolve host mail01
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best guess is that your mail server's HELO isn't configured properly - should be a fully qualified domain name (e.g. mx077.example.com), and it looks like you're just using mx072.

I don't know much about exim, but if this is the problem then it's been answered already:
[When exim4 sends HELO/EHLO, how do I configure which host name it sends?](https://serverfault.com/questions/28515/when-exim4-sends-helo-ehlo-how-do-i-configure-which-host-name-it-sends)

Comment: Where do I find out the FQDN to use? Where do I configure it? This isn't very clear from the question you linked to. I also receive an error when I reconfigure exim4 (see above).

Comment: The FQDN is the name of your server, presumably "mail.ourdomain.co.at". I don't use exim, but from what I've read  it uses a single config file that you edit then compile (and presumably restart exim service). Google for "update-exim4.conf" - blog entry at http://blog.edseek.com/~jasonb/articles/exim4_courier/exim4.html looked useful, as did http://www.exim-new-users.co.uk/

Comment: It seems I had to add the helo string to the `.template` file and then restart. Let's see if that works out.